# Add signing info to apk file name in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-app-signing

In my case, old apk file names contained the signing info unaligned and unsigned. These old file names were renamed in the module gradle file with this method:

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionCode}-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
    }
}
```

version code and version name got set like this:

```
versionCode buildNumber()
versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}"
```

in the result of this renaming, the signing info (unaligned or unsigned) was before the variant version code.

Now I'm using gradle:3.0.0-beta6. Therefore I'm not able to use the old method any more, because outputFile changed to read only and can't be renamed. Now I tried to add a new rename method to my gradle, which looks like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${variant.baseName}-${variant.versionCode}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

with this the new apk names nearly look like the old ones, but the signing info is missing between baseName and versionCode.
The app is still unsigned so there should be an unsigned info.

Does anyone know how I'm able to add this info without hardcoding?

This info should disappear if the app gets signed, but without changing the rename method if this would be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the case someone is searching for this, I solved this issue with this code:

```
 android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${variant.baseName}${variant.variantData.isSigned()?"":"-unsigned"}-${variant.versionCode}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting from Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.0 `variant.variantData.isSigned()` changed to `variant.isSigningReady()`.

Comment: @Mickverm how do you find out when it changed? it doesn't work anymore and not sure what the change is. can't find documentation on it